# Why item in Set is called value instead of key in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

`Set.prototype.forEach` which accepts a callback function in ES6 The function has 3 parameters to be consistent with `Map.prototype.forEach`. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach) says both the first 2 parameters for the callback are values because there is no keys in `Set` object. Why the item in `Set` is considered as value instead of key? No duplicated key in `Set` object would make more sense because there is also no duplicated key in `Map`.

Another aspect that value in `Set` looks like key in `Map` is that it makes `Set.prototype.has(value)` and `Map.prototype.has(key)` more consistent. Duplicated keys are NOT allowed in `Array` (key is index) and `Map`, but this cannot be extended to `Set` which doesn't allow duplicated values. Make it as duplicated keys are not allowed in all containers might be a more succinct rule.

Comment: A `Map` object has a key and a value which are separate entities.  A `Set` object just has a value which you use to add the value to the `Set` and use to test if the value is in the `Set`.  Essentially, a `Set` is indexed by the value so it's kind of like a `Set` is a `Map` where the key and value are the same.

Comment: Your last edit has driven me to a question to your own question: ***what's the question?*** :D

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer My last edit added some evidence that calling item in `Set` as key instead of value might be more appropriate. So my question ist still why the stand calls item in `Set` as value, not as key. :)

Comment: It's already answered twice :(

Answer (score 2):

It's just because the semantics of *set* collections. A *set* stores *values* while a *map* stores *keys* and *values*.

For example, both motorbikes and bicycles own two wheels, but you still say that there're motorbikes and bicycles. Just because *set* values and *map* keys are unique doesn't mean that they're the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

From the MDN link which you have attached.

> The are no keys in Set objects. However, the first two arguments are
>   both values contained in the Set, so that the callback function is
>   consistent with the forEach methods for Map and Array.

We can say that set is just an array which keeps distinct elements. There are no keys in sets.

Comment: Well most collections have an underlying array storage ;D

Comment: Well, we have to start from something :D